# One Year worth of Data based on group by within query with more groupbys

Tags: sql, where-clause

I have a query similar to this:

```
        SELECT  
        primarylocation
        , secondarylocation
        , COUNT(IDs) as members
        , SUM(observed) as observed
        , SUM(expected) as observed
        , SUM(observed)/SUM(observed) as OE
        FROM table
        WHERE
            *******date >= year(max(date)) - 1 *********
            AND BusinessRuleExcludeFLG = 0
            AND OutlierFLG = 0
        GROUP BY
            primarylocation
            , secondarylocation
```

I need a years worth of data for every primary location (so year(max(date)) - 1). The problem is with the above is it gives a years worth of data for each primary location and secondary location. Is it possible to do this in one query without a CTE?

Comment: No one can help you if no one can understand you.  Give us some context.  What are you trying to do.  Sample input???  Sample output???  Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you actually want to group by year and primary location.

```
SELECT year(date) year,
       primarylocation,
       count(ids) members,
       sum(observed) observed,
       sum(expected) expected,
       sum(observed) / sum(expected) oe
       FROM table
       WHERE businessruleexcludeflg = 0
             AND outlierflg = 0
       GROUP BY year(date),
                primarylocation;
```

(And I assume `oe` should be `sum(observed) / sum(expected)` not `sum(observed) / sum(observed)`, which would be just 1.)

Comment: The last year of data changes by location, so the year would have to go under primarylocation, but in general I think this would work. I ended up just creating a CTE that calculates the date one year back for each location then joined the table to that.